# Copying Rows from one tab to another, based on several criteria

Tags: excel, vba, copy, rows, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy rows from a tab that I imported into my document, to another tab.

```
'Clears previous data from sheet
Sheets("60L Specific Data").Select
Cells.Range("A3:AC3000").ClearContents

'Pastes Title Block from Imported into 60L sheet
Sheets("Imported Data").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("60L Specific Data").Select
Rows("3:3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Filters using several criteria
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
j = 4

For i = 2 To 2000

    If Cells(i, 28) <> "" Or Cells(i, 29) <> "" Or InStr(Cells(i, 6).Value, "K60") <> 0 Or InStr(Cells(i, 6).Value, "60T") Then

        Sheets("Imported Data").Select
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("60L Specific Data").Select
        Rows(j).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        j = j + 1
    End If
 Next i
```

Now this issue has been frustrating me.  There's a couple testing things I know you'd like to know:

First, the first two blocks of code work as intended.
Second, if you remove the if statement out it works.
Third, when I substituted in an if statements I knew had to be true for all, it did run, but any statement that would only result in some being chosen doesn't work at all.

I'm very confused and have put a lot of time into this, please help!

Comment: Looks like your source sheet is "Imported Data", but "60L Specific Data" is the active sheet when you enter the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always safer/easier to use variables to refer to your sheets, and avoid activate/select where you can:

```
Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set shtSrc = Sheets("Imported Data")
Set shtDest = Sheets("60L Specific Data")

'Clears previous data from sheet
shtDest.Range("A3:AC3000").ClearContents

'Pastes Title Block from Imported into 60L sheet
shtSrc.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=shtDest.Cells(3, 1)

j = 4
'Filters using several criteria
For i = 2 To 2000
    Set rw = shtSrc.Rows(i)
    If rw.Cells(28) <> "" Or rw.Cells(29) <> "" Or _
        InStr(rw.Cells(6).Value, "K60") <> 0 Or _
        InStr(rw.Cells(6).Value, "60T") Then

        rw.Copy shtDest.Cells(j, 1)

        j = j + 1
    End If
 Next i
```

Comment: Your code worked perfectly, I don't have very good feedback other than that it worked exactly as I had intended my code to work.  So thank you very much!  I've upvoted it, I'm not sure if there's something else I can do!